# Unusual Plots in Regression Diagnostics

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I have a dataset from Airbnb about house leasing and i am trying to create a linear model to predict overall satisfaction of a house from the other variables.

I created the following model but the Adjusted R-squared was only 0.16 and i had serious problems with the regression diagnostic plots:

```
Call:
lm(formula = overall_satisfaction ~ room_type + reviews + accommodates + 
    bedrooms, data = airb)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.1781 -2.2989  0.8342  1.6642  3.7507 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.282829   0.486577   4.692 3.91e-06 ***
room_type     0.606007   0.238844   2.537   0.0116 *  
reviews       0.013747   0.002103   6.538 2.24e-10 ***
accommodates  0.143420   0.093210   1.539   0.1248    
bedrooms     -0.528331   0.192233  -2.748   0.0063 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.049 on 346 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1776,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1681 
F-statistic: 18.68 on 4 and 346 DF,  p-value: 6.454e-14
```

[image]

Then i tried to apply a log transformation. The R-Adjusted was satisfactorily improved but the regression diagnostics were really unusual.

```
Call:
lm(formula = overall_satisfaction ~ log(room_type) + log(reviews + 
    1e-04) + log(accommodates) + log(bedrooms + 1e-04), data = airb)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5450  0.0004  0.3305  0.6978  1.6353 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            2.83488    0.25498  11.118   <2e-16 ***
log(room_type)         0.30425    0.25834   1.178    0.240    
log(reviews + 1e-04)   0.37262    0.01477  25.233   <2e-16 ***
log(accommodates)      0.17381    0.17111   1.016    0.310    
log(bedrooms + 1e-04) -0.02787    0.03032  -0.919    0.359    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.31 on 346 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.664, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6601 
F-statistic:   171 on 4 and 346 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

[image]

Could anybody explain what this shape of Normal Q-Q means and how can I improve my model?

EDIT: Addition of overall_satisfaction histogram

```
> head(airb$overall_satisfaction)
[1] 0.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 4.5 0.0
> hist(airb$overall_satisfaction)
```

[image]

Comment: *overall_satisfaction* is probably discrete, how many values do it take? Can you show us an histogram of it?

Comment: I added it in original post

Comment: That histogram is quite strange, bimodal, one group of customers is very unsatisfied and another group (somewhat larger) quite satisfied, vith few in between! Quite strange!  I would first investigate that, maybe even a logsitic regression collapsing the response into those two groups.

Comment: It would likely be overkill (and a waste of degrees of freedom) to try to run an ordinal logistic regression: the clear division between satisfied and unsatisfied customers suggests categorizing them as such and running a logistic regression on that binary response.  The treatment of room type as numerical and taking the logarithms of the other variables--which appear to be counts or classifications--is fishy.  Don't do that at first.  In short, do the simple obvious things at the outset and move on from there.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems that come to mind:  First, satisfaction is ordinal and apparently takes only 4 values in the actual data.  So, I'd use ordinal logistic regression as a first attempt but, depending on results, might combine levels 3,4 and 5 and do binary logistic regression.

Second, room type is almost certainly categorical and you have treated it as continuous.

Third, there is likely to be colinarity among the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your model cannot predict the 0 values. Try a regression 0 when it is zero and 1 when everything else.

And zeros are so far away from the other values that they work like outliers and do not allow a good estimation.